# Make https request from Node js http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, socket.io

My live site is https://example.com. Now I've created a node js server on http://example.com:8081. I've following code:

```
var options = {
    host: 'https://example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/scanner/scoutdata',
    method: 'GET'
};
and sending request like this:
http.request(options, function(res){
  //my code here.
});
```

Now I'm getting a 302 error message when I run this script in linux server.
Can't I call a url with **https://** from a **http://** node server under the same domain? Should I create my node js server in **https://** to call urls with **https://**

Answer (score 2):

Use `https.get()` instead of `http.get()` if contacting a server on port 443 (the SSL port).

The 302 response is just telling you that the port and protocol are not matching and it expects them to match.  So, use http on port 80 and https on port 443.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios

```
var axios = require('axios');

axios.get("https://example.com:443/scanner/scoutdata").then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with request module as i am putting code below-

```
request("https://example.com:443/scanner/scoutdata", function(error, response, body) { 
       console.log(body);
});
```

Thanks